# sublime 3 adds extra angular bracket on autocomplete

Tags: html, autocomplete, sublimetext3

I find on sublime 3 that if I autocomplete code I sometimes get an extra angular bracket.

for example, If I start writing `"<ht"`, I get an option to autocomplete the html tag, but the code produced looks like this:

```
<<!DOCTYPE html> <!-- Extra angle bracket here -->
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Which is quite annoying. How do I fix this? I'm not sure on what other autocompletion it does this. I'd like to start using the feature more once I know how it works and if I can adjust it to my style

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I found your solution, but keep in mind, it might bug in the coming updates.

First goto your installation destination and open the folder `Packages`, in there open `HTML.sublime-package` as archive and copy all the content in a seperate folder on your desktop. In that new folder, edit the file `html.sublime-snippet` and change

```
<content><![CDATA[<!DOCTYPE html>
```

To

```
<content><![CDATA[!DOCTYPE html>
```

This should solve your problem.

Comment: This disables autocomplete, doesn't fix the way autocomplete is working. Not helpful. At all.

Comment: [This](http://sublimetext.info/docs/en/extensibility/completions.html) or [the updated one](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/completions.html) could offer your solution.

Comment: thanks. that's very helpful. I undid my downvote, don't know who added the other one.

Answer (score 8):

Don't start off the tag with `<`. Just type `ht` and then press <kbd>Tab</kbd>, and you'll have your desired result. The same goes for any other tag.

`p` + <kbd>Tab</kbd> will create `<p></p>`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

It may be that you have a conflicting package. I had this issue with the "HTML5 Bundle" but as soon as i removed it the problem went away. Hope that helps

Comment: This should be a comment. If you don't have enough privileges, have patience.

Answer (score 2):

I just uninstall the HTML5 package from Package Control (Ctrl + Shift + P)/ Type "Remove Package" and select the packages related to HTML and it works!